Committing a jovian notebook via VS Code asks for API KEY but shows no place to enter the API KEY
I have a Jupyter notebook. I'm working in VS Code. Then I tried to commit my notebook, when I do, in the notebook I get the message/output:

[jovian] Please enter your API key ( from https://jovian.com/ ):
API KEY:

But I don't see where to enter the API KEY. I mean, I have my API KEY. I just don't see how to include it.
I even tried the following but that didn't work
import jovian
import os

jovian_api_key = os.getenv('JOVIAN_API_KEY')

jovian.commit(filename='isai-basics-01.ipynb', api_key=jovian_api_key)

It may be worth mentioning that I get see the api key if I do this from a .py file. But it shows nothing -- not even NONE -- when I run that code from a .ipynb file
